# How to hide the popup calendar of <input type="date"> in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, calendar, popup

In Firefox, `input type="date"` brings a calendar popup on click.Apart from preventing the default behaviour on click, I haven't found a way to hide the calendar. I don't want to use `type='text'` either.

Is there any way to hide this popup calendar in Firefox?

[image: popup Image]

Answer (score 3):

If you prevent the default action for the onClick handler, the popup is not shown on Firefox.

```html
<input type="date" onClick="event.preventDefault()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no way to do it properly with css in Firefox.
Instead you'll need to work with the click & focus events attached to your input.

Exemple with jQuery (can be done with vanilla JS) :

```js
$("input[type='date']").on('click, focus', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault(); //We prevent default calendar to pop
   // YOUR CODE, show your own calendar, etc
});
```