# How to remove the default calendar icon for input type "date" on Firefox, Chrome and Safari?

Tags: html, css, input

I want to remove the default calendar icon that shows up with the input type "date". [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57892727/hide-the-calendar-icon-in-google-chrome) answer works, but only for Chrome. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63636178/how-to-hide-the-popup-calendar-of-input-type-date-in-firefox) is related to hiding the popup itself, I only want to hide the icon not the popup. I haven't been able to find anything for Firefox or Safari and was wondering if it is even possible. If so, how would that be? Thanks.

Comment: [Relevant dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75855800/how-to-style-an-date-inputs-calendar-icon-in-firefox-108)